# problem with loading the spinner - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spinner, loading

I am new into ReactJS so probably I have not noticed something obvious here. The issue is that  is not visible while loading. I tried with alert and `console.log` before `return()`, it does not work too.

Here is the code, components are linked successfully:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import styled, {keyframes} from 'styled-components';
import LoaderImg from './LoaderImg.png';
import './Loader.scss';

const spinning = keyframes`
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
`;

const Spinner = styled.div`
    animation: ${spinning} 2s infinite linear;
`;

class Loader extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.handleLoad = this.handleLoad.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('load', this.loading);
        window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loading);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() { 
      window.removeEventListener('load', this.loading);
    }

    loading() {
        console.log("TEST");
        return (
            <Spinner className="Spinner">
                <img src={LoaderImg} className="Spinner-Img"/>
            </Spinner>
        );
    }
  }

export default Loader;
```

Comment: You missed render method. Please return all the jsx from render method. You placed it in loading()

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
class Loader extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.handleLoad = this.handleLoad.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('load', this.loading);
        window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loading);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() { 
      window.removeEventListener('load', this.loading);
    }

    render() {
        console.log("TEST");
        return (
            <Spinner className="Spinner">
                <img src={LoaderImg} className="Spinner-Img"/>
            </Spinner>
        );
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm afraid in this solution window.removeEventListener('load', this.loading); will not work.

Comment: Why? componentWillUnmount() will be called when this component will be unloaded, and your code will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

A render function is needed as it will be called by React in order to render/re-render the component

-either- change loading() to render()

```
render() {
    console.log("TEST");
    return (
        <Spinner className="Spinner">
            <img src={LoaderImg} className="Spinner-Img"/>
        </Spinner>
    );
}
```

-or- add:

```
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            {/* some more components */}
            {this.loading()}
        </div>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your render method? I think it's not loading becuase you have used loading() instead of render And you have not imported the Spinner object from any library or package. Try this

```
render() {
    console.log("TEST");
    return (
        <Spinner className="Spinner">
            <img src={LoaderImg} className="Spinner-Img"/>
        </Spinner>
    );
}
```

and if it doesnt work, there's a problem with your spinner. Do try this library.
[react spinners.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-spinners) This will help you to add a spinner.

Comment: Spinner is included in this component, if I will change just loading() into render()

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('load', this.loading);
        window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loading);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() { 
      window.removeEventListener('load', this.loading);
    }

will not work. :(

Answer (score 0):

You missed the render Function please add this

```
 render() {
   return (
       <>
       {this.loading()}
       </>
    )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

React docs says

> The render() method is the only required method in a class component.

You are missing it, you can do this

```
render() {
  return <>{this.loading()}</>
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Do you mean:

[...]

    loading() {
        return (
            <Spinner className="Spinner">
                <img src={LoaderImg} className="Spinner-Img"/>
            </Spinner>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return <>{this.loading()}</>
    }
[...]

?

Doesn't render the spinner. :(

Comment: that works but it's a class method that you choose to make, render is required method in a class Component that woudl call your loading method and what returns from loading will be returned from your component in this case, just add this render method after your loading method